# GetItems case sensitive from SPList (SharePoint)

Tags: case-sensitive, splist

I have troubles with `CAML Query` and `GetItems` method from `SPList`.

I get a `SPList` from web context:

```
SPList docTypeList = _web.GetList(string.Format("{0}{1}", web.ServerRelativeUrl,                                            "DocumentType"));
```

The list contains multiple values.

I want to search in it only the value which has a field called `DocumentType` with the value **"MyValue1"**. (case sensitive)

I am using the CAML Query:

```
var queryBuilder = new CAMLQueryBuilder();
            queryBuilder.AddComparison("DocumentType", CAMLQueryBuilder.COMPARISON_TYPE.Eq, "MyValue1");

var query = new SPQuery { Query = queryBuilder.GenerateCAML() };
SPListItemCollection queryResultItems = docTypeList.GetItems(query);
```

In this case it returns as result a record which has the field **"DocumentType"** having the value **"myvalue1"**, it does not take care about string sensitive.

Is there a possibility to get Items considering sensitive cases?

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on sharepoint.stackexchange.com an answer:

It's all case insensitive, after getting the results, it is necessary to iterate through and do the case sensitivity checking.

*Edit*:
Because **CAML Query is case-insensitive.**

The solution was to filter the results from

```
SPListItemCollection queryResultItems = docTypeList.GetItems(query);
```

and check for case-sensitive.

I created a small method which does this.

```
private SPListItem FindCaseSensitive(string documentType, IEnumerable items)
{
    SPListItem foundItem = null;
    if (items == null) return null;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var spItem = item as SPListItem;
        if (spItem == null) continue;

        var propertyValue = spItem["DocumentType"];
        if (!propertyValue.ToString().Equals(documentType)) continue;

        foundItem = spItem;
        break;
    }
    return foundItem;
}
```